# Angular component inheritance. How parent's life cycle hooks can be executed?

Tags: angular, typescript, prototypal-inheritance

So I have **BaseComponent** and many childs extends it:

`export class Child1Component extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit`

**Child1Component** does not call `super.ngAfterViewInit()`, but for some reason BaseComponent AfterViewInit is executed. I just console it log:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('BaseComponent AfterViewInit')
}
```

How is that possible? What else except of `super.ngAfterViewInit()` can call parent's life cycle hook?

Could this be happening only in development mode?

Comment: Does `ngAfterViewInit` execute on every child component or just once?

Comment: Yes, it is executed many times, but nothing in the whole app calls `super.ngAfterViewInit()` (and to clarify - it is executed not on child, but in **BaseComponent** `AfterViewInit`)\

Comment: Did you define `ngAfterViewInit` on the child component?

Comment: wait so lifecycle hooks Are inherited? this article says differently plus many others https://medium.com/@saniyusuf/part-1-the-case-for-component-inheritance-in-angular-a34fe2a0f7ac

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's normal OOP inheritance behaviour. If you don't explicitly define the `ngAfterViewInit` on the child component, then this component will have the the parent implementation of that method available.

So, during components lifecycle, when angular checks wether the `ngAfterViewInit` method is available on the child component, then the answser is yes: the child component has that method implemented, but it's inherited from the parent component

Comment: I just came back to post this answer :D

Comment: Glad I answered first ;)

Comment: wait so lifecycle hooks are inherited? this article says different https://medium.com/@saniyusuf/part-1-the-case-for-component-inheritance-in-angular-a34fe2a0f7ac

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 I think the article is wrong: in OOP, when a child class inherits a base class, methods from the base class are inherited in the child class

Comment: @David The article is not technically wrong; it's just not explained very well.

If the base has an ngOnInit method and the extending class does not - then the base method will be triggered during the component lifecycle without doing anything.

But if the extending class also has an ngOnInit method, then the base event method will only get fired if the extending class method "bubbles down" to it by calling super.ngOnInit() during the extending class' event method.

Answer (score 5):

the child componenet will have (inherent) **all base component class property and method** so normally the child class will have `ngAfterViewInit` method and this will run by angular ,in case you want to overwrite this method simplly recreate this at the child class and this will take present over the method in the base class , but even you can access to the base class by using  **super** keyword

```
export class Child1Component extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    super.ngAfterViewInit(); //  call base ngAfterViewInit method  
    console.log('Child1Component AfterViewInit');
  }

}
```

> ngAfterViewInit is special method it one of lifecycle hooks a method
>   run and manage by angular , read more about this  [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: wait so lifecycle hooks Are inherited? this article says differently plus many others https://medium.com/@saniyusuf/part-1-the-case-for-component-inheritance-in-angular-a34fe2a0f7ac

Comment:  @Artportraitdesign1 that totally wrong  , check this demo and it 's same as the article code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4f2df

Comment: so they are giving out fake information? thanks for letting me know, surprised a highly index google article on medium would do that

Answer (score 1):

From the [**Docs**](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence):

> [`ngAfterViewInit()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngAfterViewInit)
>
> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views / the view that a directive is in.
>
> Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().

As you can see that its the normal behavior in case of `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: so wait lifecycle hooks are inherited? this article says different,  https://medium.com/@saniyusuf/part-1-the-case-for-component-inheritance-in-angular-a34fe2a0f7ac